# how to model my data is angular js? Does something like Backbone.Model will fit?

Tags: javascript, backbone.js, angularjs

I am using angular-js and I am looking for a way to model my data. I am inspired by Backbone and started to write something similar to Backbone model. In Backbone model there are get() and set() methods for accessing model's members.
What is the advantages of using get() and set() methods over using model.attributes.*_*_?
If I don't need my angular models to trigger changes events, does it worth to create get() and set() methods that are similar to Backbone.Model's get() and set()?

**EDIT**
To be more clear, I am asking if there is advantage to make a set() and get() methods over direct access to the fields. If there is no any advantage, why does Backbone people decided to go that way?

Comment: What's wrong with a plain JavaScript object to model an object? Unlike Backbone, Angular lets you stick to JavaScript for handling the M in MVC and handles the rest for you :) (also, no ugly `get`, `set` , when you change stuff in controllers it'll automagically know)

Comment: Plain JavaScript object can not maintain state, trigger or listen to events, you cannot put on them model related logic methods and so on.

Comment: Of course it can, that's the entire point of variables... they maintain state in your application. Backbone forces you to use `Backbone.model` for stuff because it's a primitive deprecated framework designed in a time where people did not know how to build web apps yet. If you just stick it in `$scope` Angular will automagically keep track of what happens to it for you or you can use $apply . Angular sports data binding, you don't need to notify it when things change, it'll figure it out on its own. Here is an Angular tutorial to get you started http://www.egghead.io/

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: When you develop large scale application, there are a lot of models that are bind one to each other. Not just models to views. More then that, here is an example where plain object has no ability to solve: I have an object that manage data for user. This object listen to an event that called 'user-logged-out'. Whenever user logged out, this object knows to clear its data. Up to here I didn't even mentioned controllers. If you are building large scale application, you must design your data.

Comment: The fact the model is even aware of the UI interactions shows a poor design imo. The model in MV* should not even be aware of the fact it's part of a UI environment - for the very least that fact should not be forced by the framework. The fact the model receives 'user-logged-out' shows bad separation of concerns to begin with in my opinion. Moreover, it's fairly easy to make an object an event emitter even without backbone in JavaScript. Anyway, security should probably sit in a different domain, most likely as a service (I think the word I want is _aspect_).

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: Log out is NOT UI interaction, but user interaction. IMO, I don't think you can answer the question I asked so  if you don't have relevant answer to my question, I done the conversation with you.

Comment: @Naor The integral nature behind angular is that the model itself should not be aware of such user actions, even at the level of listening for an emitted event. The controller handles all of that. If you have a model that needs to be cleared when the user logs out, the controller handling the view containing the logout button (a UI action) would have the service containing the model injected into it and that same controller would call the clear function declared on the model in the service. All of which is done in plain old javascript.

Answer (score 3):

You just need to create a service which would hold the data, you can think of services like instances of models or collections. For example, you have some domain class like `Book`, what you can do is to create a service 'BookListService' which would be responsible for CRUD and/or business logic.

Something like this

```
function Book(title, author){
   this.title = title;
   this.author = author;
   this.isRead = false;
}

Book.prototype.markAsRead = function(){
   this.isRead = true
}



angular.module('someModule', []).factory('BookListService', function($http){
   var service {
         books: [],
         load: function(){
             $http.get('/books').then(function(res){
                 angular.forEach(res.data, function(book){
                     service.books.push(new Book(book.title, book.author))
                 })
             })
         }
    };
    return service; 
})
```

Comment: I know that. I am asking if there is advantage to make a set() and get() methods over direct access to the fields. If there is no any advantage, why does Backbone people decided to go that way?

Comment: @Naor Because Backbone is a naive lightweight implementation and Angular is a full blown framework backed by people like Misko Havery.

Comment: @Benjamin Gruenbaum: Call Angular a "full blown framework" is naive.

Answer (score 1):

Angular's 'models' are any object in javascript.

If you check out the tutorials on angularjs.org,

http://jsfiddle.net/api/post/library/pure/

The data is defined in the Controller. So make an array, just do

```
$scope.todos = [
    {text:'learn angular', done:true},
    {text:'build an angular app', done:false}];
```

To get/set is just normal javascript:

get length: $scope.todos.length;

set to empty: $scope.todos = [];

In the view (html), just call the variable if its under the same Controller

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
    <span>{{todos.length}}</span>
</div>
```

Comment: I know that. I am trying to model my json data in a real "class" that can handle state, make logics, listen and bind to events. What you answer has no relation to model a data.

Answer (score 0):

I had some trouble with this at first because Angular seems overwhelming, so I was expecting a big answer for model implementation. The answer is simply to use JS objects. Angular has all of the tools you need to easily create a model yourself without the use of Backbone (which I have also read is not really the way to go with Angular). If you look into `$emit`, `$broadcast`, `$on`, you have your events for model updates. If you want to create instances of the objects rather than singletons, then have your factory return an instance. A good place to start I think is [angular-app](https://github.com/angular-app/angular-app). Apologies if this isn't specific enough.

If you are looking for a package to use, try [BreezeJS](http://www.breezejs.com/home).